# Algorithm for reverse topology sorting

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, graph-traversal

I'm looking for an efficient algorithm to resolve the dependencies of a series of modules in a dependency graph, with the following constraints:

- The algorithm can take as input one or more start nodes.
- The dependencies of these nodes are calculated such that their loading can be parallelized.
- Should the graph not to be acyclic, an error must be thrown.
- Its complexity should be as small as possible (no need to visit non-required nodes) – the graph may contain billions of nodes, only a fraction of which are necessary for each query.

**Goal example**

In this example, the two nodes in green are provided as starting points.  The node in red is never visited. Each node in white is visited. Loading is scheduled to be performed in steps (indicated inside the node).

[image]

Do you have any hint on an algorithm that would respect these rules?

Comment: In your diagram it appears the middle `2` node depends on the right `2` node. Why can they load at the same time?

Comment: My mistake. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be solved by using topological sorting, which is desribed in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) Wikipedia article; note that the article is redirected from "dependency resolution". The running time of the described algorithm is

```
O(|V| + |E|)
```

where `V` is the set of nodes and `E` is the set of edges, i.e. the running time is linear in the size of the input.

Comment: Thanks, I've visited this page before. Problem is that the two algorithms presented do not seem to conform to the requirements for two reasons. Khan's algorithm starts from the leaves, which is opposite to what I'm trying to achieve. Both Kahn's and DFS visit all nodes, which is a problem in a very large graph – typically a query only returns a small fraction of the graph.

Comment: @Pierre first make a dfs/bfs starting from your starting nodes to visit all nodes they point to (their required dependencies). Then do toposort in this small set of nodes